# How to post URL links into SoundCloud comments

Tags: soundcloud

Hopefully this should be an easy one for someone out there - but how do you include live links in SoundCloud comments? I've read it's possible but not sure what formatting they use or if it's the reg some text format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal HTML links should work.

Depending on which app or API client you use to look at the result, it might be displayed slightly differently, though.

Comment: Cool - thanks @Marco, you're right it did work with normal <a href ... all looks good from within SoundCloud, however, when you view a SoundCloud clip via a third party sight (via <i frame) the link doesn't show instead reads as the code <a href ______ target= ...  is there a work-around for this, or just something to put up with?

Comment: The API returns html tags encoded for security reasons, so the client displaying them would have to decode them if it wants to. It'd also have to deal with the security implications of it, though (XSS).

Comment: @Overdose: I knew this was a topic being discussed a while back, but I'm no longer working for SoundCloud, and I'm not sure if they changed anything now, sorry.